# Adding query inside concat for images having specific imageType such as profile or poster in MySql select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have image table in which I have two `imageType` called profile and poster in `imageType` field and I have only on image path where I am storing all images URL.

If possible I want something like:

```
CONCAT('/images/', select i.path where i.imageType='**poster**') AS posters

CONCAT('/images/', select i.path where i.imageType='**profile**') AS profiles

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(f.filmReleaseDate,'%d %b %Y')filmReleaseDate, f.filmName, CONCAT('/images/', i.path) AS profiles, CONCAT('/images/', i.path) AS posters, f.filmDirector, url FROM films f
    INNER JOIN images i ON f.filmId = i.filmId
    WHERE f.filmReleaseDate >= NOW() 
    GROUP by i.filmId
    ORDER BY DATE(f.filmReleaseDate)
    LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: you may have to aggregate the data if there are two rows in image; but then I don't see why you would have only one path then... but perhaps Use a case statement?`CONCAT('/images/', case when i.imageType = 'poster' then i.path end ) AS posters`  to better understand I would need to see sample data in images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(f.filmReleaseDate,'%d %b %Y')filmReleaseDate, f.filmName, 
  case when  i.imageType='**profile**' then  CONCAT('/images/', i.path) end AS profiles, 
  case when  i.imageType='**poster**' then CONCAT('/images/', i.path) end AS posters, f.filmDirector, url FROM films f
    INNER JOIN images i ON f.filmId = i.filmId
    WHERE f.filmReleaseDate >= NOW() 
    GROUP by i.filmId
    ORDER BY DATE(f.filmReleaseDate)
    LIMIT 0 , 10
```

For gettin both together try a inner join with the same table

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(f.filmReleaseDate,'%d %b %Y')filmReleaseDate, f.filmName, 
        CONCAT('/images/', i.path) AS profiles, 
        CONCAT('/images/', j.path) AS posters, f.filmDirector, url FROM films f
    INNER JOIN images i ON f.filmId = i.filmId
    INNER JOIN images j on (j.filmId = i.filmId)
    WHERE f.filmReleaseDate >= NOW() 
    AND i.imageType='**profile**'
    AND j.imageType='**poster**'
    GROUP by i.filmId
    ORDER BY DATE(f.filmReleaseDate)
    LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: profile is coming correctly but poster is coming as null

Comment: Anyway i have update the asnwer with **profile** and **poster**

Comment: thanks a lot... it worked, my mistake....limit and release date was stopping poster to display.

Comment: its coming like this not both together: 
this is profile: **29 Jan 2016 /images/filmprofile.jpg NULL**,.......
this is poster**29 Jan 2016 NULL /images/filmPoster.jpg**

Comment: i mean when profile is displaying poster is null and when poster is displaying profile is null, not both together

Comment: You need both together ?

Comment: Yes both together like **/images/filmprofile.jpg** and **/images/filmposter.jpg** one for cover photo kind of and other for profile photo like facebook..i dont want to create one more field.

Comment: it restricts other data to display from, only corresponds to images which having poster and profile, other film details from films table not displaying.

Comment: I don't undertstand  .. the other films detail are form films f table and the inner join on image don't should do this if the al the films have both poster and profile .. image..

Comment: most of them are not having poster and if no poster available then also all the 10 details should display with some placeholder that i will take care in frontend side